# Layers of Shapefiles are not overlapping

Tags: qgis

I have analysed Spacial Poisson of the data from Nepal by using SaTscan and tried to join all the coordinates BY QGIS but it shows map and the points are in different locations.

I have already checked the X Y code is OK and matched with Nepal Data.

Comment: The most frequent reason why two layers don't overlap is that they are not in the same coordinate systems. If I was you, I would check it twice.